# Edit arraylist with the number not the index

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How to edit the arraylist using the value and not the index number? with the use of arraylist.set( 93, 92)

```
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); 
    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Generates arraylsit with size 10 with random integers from 1 to 100
    for (int j = 0; j<10; j++)
    {
        pick = rand.nextInt(100);
        al.add(pick);
    }
 System.out.println("Please enter an integer to update or edit: ");
             int toUpdateInt = sc.nextInt();
             System.out.println("Please eneter the new value of data: ");
             int newValue = sc.nextInt();
             al.set(toUpdateInt, newValue);
             System.out.println(al);
```

In my code it asks for the index number in the (toUpdateInt) I want to use the random number to set. How to?

Comment: You have to do a linear search, see if you have the random matching toUpdateInt - get the index and then update it with new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Arraylist.contains() method, but this would be fine.

```
if(a1.indexOf(toUpdateInt) != -1) {
    a1.set(a1.indexOf(toUpdateInt), newValue);
    } else {
    a1.add(newValue);
    System.out.println("The integer to update is not available, and hence added it.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a `Set` (no duplicates, no order) it would be fast and easy.

```
Set<Integer> al = new HashSet<>();
Random rand = new Random();
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    int pick = rand.nextInt(100);
    al.add(pick);
}

...
al.remove(toUpdateInt);
al.add(newValue);
```

For a `List`:

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();

int index = al.indexOf(toUpdateInt);
if (index != -1) {
    al.set(index, newValue);
}
```

Comment: Can you fix the typo - `al.index(...` should be `al.indexOf(...`